# Reorganizing data with in a file

Tags: java, file

I'm working with a preexisting file system here, so I can't alter the structure of it. Also I'm working in Java, using a RandomAccessFile object.

One file can hold many independent chunks of data. I know where to find the right file and the start of each individual chunk without any problems, as well as know its exact size. The file is divided into 4 KB "sectors" where data can only start at the beginning of a sector. Chunks of data are of varying size. This is all well and good until the size varies enough that the number of sectors needed to hold it changes... A chunk can be anywhere between 4 and 256 sectors, so it's not a trivial matter where I can just give each chunk extra space in case it grows.

I need to find a way to save this edited chunk back to the file, but it doesn't fit where it used to, so I have to make space. I can easily update all the metadata that tells me where everything is now stored, that's not an issue. The issue is that I don't know an efficient way to shift data around in this file. the file will have 1024 chunks of data, each ranging from 4 to 256 sectors (16 KB to 1MB). So this file has the potential to be 1 GB in size. Loading the file in all at once is out of the question.

My first thought was to do a sort of ripple effect. Let Chunk A be the one I'm now saving a larger, modified version of. Reserve a sector's worth of memory in my program, load the first sector after after Chunk A's old position, save it where Chunk A used to start, and keep shifting the subsequent sectors back until the end of the file, then finally tack the new sector onto the end. I can't help but feel that idea is horrifically inefficient. Does anyone have a better one?

If it helps, I have easy, constant time access to the position of every chunk in the file and how many sectors each one takes up. It's all in the file header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing is pretty much the problem of fragmentation. Or maybe I should say that fragmentation is usually the result of avoiding excessive moving around of data when it changes. The best thing you can do is look at the existing solutions for both disk and memory fragmentation to get ideas. It's an issue that has existed for as long as computers have had storage (both volatile and persistent) so it's well-studied.

On a file system, files would correspond to your `chunks` of data, the file table being a form of your `header`. File systems have the luxury of being capable of breaking up a file into pieces that don't have to form a contiguous block on disk. Since you can't change the file format you have to maintain, you don't have the option of breaking up the chunks and keeping, say, a pointer at the end of a chunk to its continuation. But when changing a file so it becomes larger than where it currently fits, the file system is obviously not going to move all subsequent files to make room. That would be a horrendously expensive operation. Similarly, you don't want to be moving around all chunks after the edited one. Because physical disk access for mechanical media (rotating magnetic discs) becomes increasingly inefficient if data belonging together (such as for one file) is all over the place, occasional defragmenting is applied where the time-consuming tasks of moving files to use space more efficiently is performed in one batch.

In memory, programs are going to have to allocate memory to work with. The operating system can take chunks of available memory from the physical memory space and present those to the programs it hosts as if each program had its own contiguous memory space. This is a necessary abstraction to make sure that programs can run in isolation without having to keep track of each other. Programs are constantly going to allocate space and de-allocate it as they process data, which causes fragmentation of the available memory. Sometimes, however, a certain amount of contiguous memory (as seen by the program) is required, like for a large byte array. If no such block of available memory exists in the program's memory space, data will have to be moved about until the free memory pools together in a sufficiently large block. If that can't be done, you get out of memory errors. For some ideas of how these things are done, investigate the [C programming language memory allocation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

The take-away from the above is this: **don't try to keep the file at an optimal size at all times if you don't have to, but when the time allows or situation demands it, re-arrange it.**

Let's take a look at an example. Suppose you have 3 chunks, of sizes 4, 8 and 6 sectors respectively. The header keeps track of where each chunk starts.

[image: initial situation]

We'd now edit chunk 2 and it becomes 10 sectors long. It no longer fits within its current space. So we go through the file to find the first address where there is enough free space for 10 sectors, move the edited chunk there and update the header. Note that the old data can just remain or can be blanked.

[image: new situation]

In order to find the first free block of space that is sufficiently large to hold a new or edited chunk, we need to investigate the header to map out the memory use in the file. For example, the new situation leaves 8 unused sectors, from address 4 to 11. If no free block of space can be found that is sufficiently large, you'd put the chunk at the end. The file will then have to grow in size.

So how do we keep the fragmentation in check? There would have to be an occasional analysis of the file space usage. Using the header and maybe keeping some metadata during updates, this could be pretty simple and wouldn't take too much processing. If certain criteria are met (for example, 20% of the file consists of unused sectors) you initiate a round of defragmenting. If a chunk must be placed at the end of the file, but there is no space left (1 GiB used), you'd first try to do a round of defragmenting and then moving the edited chunk or adding the new one. If the defragmenting didn't free up enough space, you've run into a limit (like the out-of-memory error in a program).

The defragmenting approach could be very simple, or clever, depending on how fast it needs to be. Simple would be: just shift every chunk in the order it appears in the file so it starts at the end of the one before it.

[image: moving chunks]

This guarantees that after you're done the file will have its smallest possible size. However, because it leaves no "open room" you're going to introduce fragmentation again the first time you edit a chunk in a way that makes it larger, because it would by definition no longer fit (unless it's the last one in the file). Also, it's going to move all chunks starting from the first one that has empty space in front of it, so it's an expensive operation.

You could try smarter approaches to get some more speed out of it, such as going through the chunks from the end of the file and moving each into the empty space that best fits it when searching from the start of the file. This wouldn't move all the chunks. Some unused space would remain, but less than before.

How you model your defragmentation algorithm depends on your use-case. You could even choose dynamically, such as the heavy approach when you reach the maximum file size, and a much quicker, lighter algorithm if you just exceed a certain threshold of unused space.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ideas would be that each modification you will create a new file. So say you go through cycle of modifications, and once done you create a new file and write all the chunks modified and not modified into new file with new order and journal (tracking of your chunks coordinates).
Pros: gives you history for each modification, relatively simple logic
Cons: Disk space inefficient, may be inefficient in writing if the modified chunks are small portion of the entire file.
By far more complex idea is to store just original file and the sequence of deltas for each modification. Then on retrieving you will have to dynamically build the state of chunk based on it's original state and the deltas relevant to this particular chunk

Comment: This is exaclty how (exif-, iptc-, xmp-) metadata is handled in a jpg files

Comment: The problem with the first idea is I'm potentially writing as few as 4 chunks in a single write, and there are 1024 chunks per file, so the space inefficiency and time of writing out the whole file over and over again for each of those is really sticking out there. For the writes where I'm changing 500 or so chunks at once, that starts to make more sense, but that isn't always the case.

Could you explain your second idea in more detail?

Comment: While I do understand why the first idea is unattractive to you, I would actually still strongly consider it as the second one is a complex implementation and has some drawbacks on its own. But anyway the idea is that you keep your original file and every time you change something you will need to write into a separate file(s) what chunk was changed and how, so whenever you need to retrieve a chunk you will need to read the original chunk and then go through your history of changes that apply to your chunk and apply each change that was done to this chunk in appropriate order.

Comment: So once you apply all changes to your original chunk you will get your chunk in its current state. This is a known pattern that is used in many systems. It is most efficient when the amount of changes is significantly smaller then the original info. For instance it is used in a disk backup system that keeps only 1 original copy of the entire disk and records of changes, as usually changes on disk are much smaller then the entire disk. But be forewarned that proper implementation of this algorithm is complex. So, consider the first one as it is very simple